# Toggle instead of going to page with URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating different style of navigation in mobile view. The three links that has + sign has their link on desktop view but I want in mobile when clicked, the sub menu will toggle. How can I do that if the 3 links has href? How to prevent the link going to the another page?

[image]

This is my code

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var width = $(document).width();
if (width >= 320) {
    $("ul#main-menu li").on("click", function() {
      $(this).next().find('ul.sub-menu').css("display", "block");
      $(this).next().find('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle(300);
      return false;
    });
}

else {
    $("ul#main-menu li").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        var thiswidth = $(this).css('width');
        thiswidth = parseInt(thiswidth);
        thiswidth = thiswidth / 2;
        var nbsub = $(this).find('.sub-menu').children().length;
        submulti = 257;
        if($(this).hasClass('petite')){
            submulti = 206;
        }
        subwidth = (nbsub * submulti);
        subwidthhalf = subwidth / 2;
        if($(this).hasClass('premier')){
            subwidthhalf = subwidthhalf - 75 ;
        }
        if($(this).hasClass('milieu')){
            subwidthhalf = subwidthhalf + 156;
        }
        if($(this).hasClass('dernier')){
            subwidthhalf = subwidthhalf + 368 ;
        }
        subleft = (thiswidth - subwidthhalf);           
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').css('width',subwidth + 'px');
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').css('left',subleft + 'px');
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').css('display','block');
        }, function() {
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').css('width','auto');
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').css('left','-9999px');
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').css('display','none');
    });
});

}
});
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`, of course, you need to check for the element clicked

Comment: how to do that? I added event.preventDefault(); replace the code return false but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

When you add an event binder, the first parameter to the function you define will be the event itself. Knowing that, there are various things you can call on an event. One thing is `preventDefault` which would prevent the default action. You would modify your code to this (assuming the `a` or anchor tags with the `href` are inside the `li` tags):

```
if (width >= 320) {
    $("ul#main-menu li").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().find('ul.sub-menu').css("display", "block");
      $(this).next().find('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle(300);
      return false;
    });
}
```

If you want it to happen even if the width is < 320, you'd need to add another event binding to do the same thing. Like so:

```
if (width >= 320) {
    $("ul#main-menu li").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().find('ul.sub-menu').css("display", "block");
      $(this).next().find('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle(300);
      return false;
    });
} else {
   $("ul#main-menu li").on("click", function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
   });
   ... 
}
```

Note that it would be cleaner to target the anchor tags directly and prevent the click action from triggering the default behavior. Mostly because it would be more obvious what you're targeting and why for other programs who come along later.

[MDN: Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: the "default" click action on an `<li>` is ... nothing ... how does preventing *nothing* change the behaviour of this code

Comment: @JaromandaX Wrong. It depends on if the anchor tags are inside the list item tags. If so, https://jsfiddle.net/j86yoe7r/ -- the binding will catch them. I do agree it would be better to target the anchor tags directly but without complete examples, there is always a lot of guessing and the answer gets them far enough along they can fix the problem. I'll add a note though. Based on the code, I took a guess (320 pixel `li` hints it's the menu block).

Comment: there is no indication that anchor tags exist in the original code, so ... my bad